# Automate updating external database from Dynamics 365 and Azure

Tags: javascript, api, azure, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

The company has used Dynamics CRM for years, and at some point into the coming months, I need to look into integrating the client data from it into our other web applications.

Our current setup is that Dynamics 365 has the most current client data, we manually export it and manually import it into another database that drives the web applications. Not very efficient, and as one would expect, there are cases throughout the year were this manual process doesn't happen and something is out of date or inaccurate in the web application database.

I do have a Python application I wrote that handles the OAuth authentication and can request specific bits of data via the Dynamics 365 Web API and update the database. So I do have sorted out how to request records on demand, but this seems like it will slow the application down.

What I am wondering is if there is a way FROM Dynamics 365, that once a record is updated there it will update or create the record in an external database? That way the external database is always up to date, a request to Dynamics 365's web API doesn't have to be sent, and the web application should be faster in general.

Would this be an Azure custom process, custom JS in Dynamics 365 that utilizes the web application's API to update/create records in the external database when a record is updated/created in Dynamics 365, or some other process?

Comment: It seems like an [Azure Aware Plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/write-custom-azure-aware-plugin) would fit the bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I havent tried this myself I'd start looking at Web Hooks. It appears to be right down your alley.

[Link to WebHooks Documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2016/01/15/sending-webhooks-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm/)

Comment: This sounds really promising, thanks for the suggestion! Definitely sounds more straight forward than the Azure Aware plugin that was recommended and like it would integrate more seamlessly with our infrastructure than the Data Export Service. Here is Dynamics 365 documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-webhooks. Will keep you posted as I roll this out over the coming month.

Answer (score 1):

The [Data Export Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt744592.aspx) could be the thing you are looking for. It will keep an Azure SQL database in sync with the records in Dynamics 365 CE (CRM).

> The Microsoft Dynamics 365-Data Export Service is an add-on service made available on Microsoft AppSource that adds the ability to replicate Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) data to a Microsoft Azure SQL Database store in a customer-owned Microsoft Azure subscription. The supported target destinations are Microsoft Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on Microsoft Azure virtual machines. The Data Export Service intelligently synchronizes the entire Dynamics 365 data initially and thereafter synchronizes on a continuous basis as changes occur (delta changes) in the Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) system. This helps enable several analytics and reporting scenarios on top of Dynamics 365 data with Azure data and analytics services and opens up new possibilities for customers and partners to build custom solutions.

Do note though that [Microsoft doesn't provide an SLA on the Data Export Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt744592.aspx#About%20data%20synchronization%20latency) (last paragraph).

Comment: Sounds promising, thanks for the suggestion. Just to clarify, this would work with Azure Database for PostgreSQL? That is where will be storing our data and I understand it to be a "flavor" of Azure Database. Lastly, how about databases outside of Azure? This other piece of software we are likely going to be using for project management has its own backend hosted on the developers servers, which is off limits to us. They only have an API which we can use to update records, so would need to send an HTTP request from Dynamics or Azure to `PUT` and `CREATE`.

Comment: I don't think it would work with PostgreSQL, since it explicitly states Azure SQL Database or SQL Server. We're using it with an Azure SQL Database.

Comment: As an aside, don't underestimate how many requests a Dynamics Online instance can properly handle. I understand the solution from a decoupling perspective, but performance shouldn't be the main driver here. Decoupling and keeping in sync is hard, so you might want to look into directly connecting to CRM.